# javascript: passing a function name vs. IIFE

Tags: javascript, function, iife

(Hoping I've got the terminology right...)

My code, much simplified:

```
function foo(parm1, fn){
    // do stuff with parm1, and then...
    window[fn]();
}

function bar(){
    // do the other thing
}
```

Which is then invoked as:

```
foo('some string', 'bar');
```

I'd like to use a function expression(?), like so:

```
foo('some string', function(){ // do the other thing });
```

while retaining the option to pass a function name as in the first example for when what 'bar' has to do is many steps. I've tried

```
function foo(parm1, fn){
    // do stuff with parm1, and then...
    if(typeof fn != 'function'){
        window[fn]();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

foo('some string', function(){ // but this never fires });
```

Can I have it both ways?

Comment: `function foo(parm1, fn){
        // do stuff with parm1, and then...
        if(typeof fn !== 'function'){
            window[fn]();
        } else {
            fn();
        }
    }
    
    foo('some string', function(){ console.log('function callback...'); });`

Comment: To prevent errors if the second param is a string but not a global function, you could also check `typeof window[fn] == 'function'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. You forgot to call `fn` if it is a function:

```
if(typeof fn != 'function'){
    window[fn]();
} else {
    fn(); // fn is (probably) a function so lets call it
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using type checking (`!==`).